# ODBC 32-Bit System DSN Intermittent Connect Crash

Tags: database, db2, crystal-reports, odbc

I work for a small Credit Union. A lot of my work deals with Crystal Report software. After upgrading to a new laptop, I found that Crystal Reports would frequently crash whenever I tried to run a report or view the SQL command used to create it. At first I thought this was a Crystal Reports issue. I uninstalled and reinstalled. No change. I even tried to uninstall the IBM DB2 connections and then reinstall those. Still no change.

I found that the crashes occur even in ODBC 32-Bit as well, which leads me to believe it is not a Crystal Reports issue, but an ODBC / database issue. We have two connections we use. One is a live database, the other is a 1 day delay. I set up a System DSN connection in ODBC 32-Bit and 64-Bit for each (total of four). I can do a connection test to both 64-Bit connections without issue. However, on either of the 32-Bit connections, 9 times out of 10 the ODBC program will time out and stop responding until I manually close it.

Does anyone have any ideas about what could possibly be causing this? I have even recently reimaged the whole laptop and reinstalled everything from scratch. I'm at a total loss. Especially on why sometimes they will connect, and then immediately afterwards not connect.

Like I said. I have reinstalled everything. Reimaged. Everything from scratch essentially. Not sure what else I could even look to do.

Comment: This is  not a programming question. It is about configuration. The solution is often to enforce that the `db2level` of the  installed Db2 components is updated to the latest levels (or final fixpack that is compatible with the Db2-server software). Usually with a new laptop, comes a new or altered version of the operating-sytem, which in turn often requires a more up-to-date fixpack level of the Db2-components that are installed on the laptop.

Answer (score -1):

What kind of database do you use ? Try OLEDB instead of ODBC.